# Are the local file entry headers in a zip file compressed along with the actual file/folder entry data?

Tags: zip

The picture [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/63/ZIP-64_Internal_Layout.svg/800px-ZIP-64_Internal_Layout.svg.png) which is linked from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29%E2%80%8E) gives a good overview of the zip archive structure.

What is less clear from the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29%E2%80%8E) is whether the local file headers are compressed along with their associated data (nb. if compression has indeed been used at all). Can anyone shed some light on this?

Cheers.

Comment: No, the local headers are not compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, local headers are not compressed. The central directory can be compressed and/or encrypted, but this seems to be supported only by PKWare and other commercial libraries (like SecureBlackbox).